# graph database using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[csv dataset of epl league 2000-2110](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjPrC.png)

Can I get help writing the following Cypher query?

```
1) List all teams that have ever played EPL matches since 2000.
2) Display all matches “Liverpool” won against “Man United” since 2010. 
3) Display the top five referees and the number of matches they refereed since 2000. 
4) Display all teams and the total number of goals they scored and conceded in the 2020/21 season;
5) Which team had the best home-winning record since 2000. 
6) Which team lost the most matches in the 2020/21 season?
7) Which teams lost the 1st half but won the match in the 2020/21 season? ***
8) Which team earned the highest-ever points in all seasons since 2000? 
9) Display the final league table ranking of all teams in the 2020/21 season (based on the total points).
10) Which team had the longest unbeaten record;
```

I have tried the following codes for questions 2 and 3 respectively

```
MATCH (l:Team)-[:PLAYED_AWAY]->(m:Match)<-[:PLAYED_HOME]-(u:Team)
WHERE l.name = 'Liverpool' AND u.name = 'Man United' AND l.ftr > u.ftr AND m.season >= '2000-01'
RETURN m.season, l.name, l.ftr, u.name, u.ftr

MATCH (ref:Referee)-[:REFEREED_BY]->(m:Match)
WHERE m.datetime >= datetime('2000-08-19T00:00:00Z') 
WITH ref, count(ref) as Referee
ORDER BY Referee DESC
LIMIT 5
RETURN ref.name as Referees, Referee
```

Comment: what is not correct on your answers to q2 and q3? Besides this is your school assignment, so you must do it on your own.

Comment: A question that asks too many different things at the same time risks being [forced closed by the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things). You should consider asking about #2 and #3 in 2 separate questions, and omit all the other homework items.

Comment: This is obviously a homework and not appropriate in stack overflow.